# Using GeoJSON as an input for GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geojson, api

I have an ArcGIS Online API that I would like to use as an input/store in my GeoServer so that I can publish a service from GeoServer. The format available thorough the API is GeoJSON. I can see that there is an option of adding a WFS as a vector data source but the service I have does not have any WFS or WMS capabilities on and has only GeoJSON output format.

Answer (score 2):

At present, probably no. While [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) does have a [GeoJSON datastore](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/tree/master/modules/unsupported/geojsonstore) that could be added to [GeoServer](https://geoserver.org) it is currently unsupported, has no documentation and lacks the GeoServer wrapper that would provide you with a GUI element to allow you to set it up easily.

You can give it a try by adding the `gt-geojsonstore` jar file (and dependencies) to the `WEB-INF/lib` directory but I really don't know what would happen.

You could seek [commercial support](http://geoserver.org/support/) to finish up the work on the module and integrate it into GeoServer, or provide the needed code yourself.

Or you could prevail on the service provider to use an open standard (like WFS) to publish the data rather than a vendor encumbered one.

Comment: "vendor encumbered"

GeoJSON is not "vendor encumbered", its an IETF standard, ( RFC 7946 to be precise ). Thats not to say its a *good* standard, but its one thats generally pretty easy to generate from most standard geometry stores.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that what you get out of an ESRI server isn't standard GeoJSON but an embraced and extended version

Comment: Fair point lol. 
If you want to see me angry-rant, give me a couple of beers and ask me about Unicode and XML in ESRIs older products (Specifically giving the XML a UTF-8 encoding attribute and then encoding the rest as UTF-16, or perhaps the other way I forget. Heavens have mercy)