# Using GeoJSON Datastore and GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geojson, geotools, json

I found a way that should allow to use `(Geo-)JSON` flies with GeoServer: An unsupported GeoTools `GeoJSON Datastore` (using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/386477/176525))

Here is a link to the `jar`: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-geojsondatastore/24.2

I dropped the `jar` into the `WEB-INF` => `lib` of GeoServer, but nothing happend to the GeoServer interface.

What else do I have to do to make the `GeoJSON Datastore` be running to use `JSON` files with GeoServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in [my answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367255/79) the GeoJSONDatastore module is **unsupported** that means that you use it at your own risk and accept the need to investigate and fix any issues you may find using it.

I had a quick look over the weekend and I can get the latest (25-SNAPSHOT) version to install into GeoServer but not actually display the data on a map. Feel free to proceed from here with debugging it and providing a PR to improve the datastore.

Since displaying GeoJSON data through GeoServer will be slow and cumbersome I doubt that I will spend much of my spare time trying to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/367255/109339 the GeoTools GeoJSON Datastore "lacks the GeoServer wrapper that would provide you with a GUI element to allow you to set it up easily".

Maybe there is a way to configure a `datasource.xml` in the data-directory of GeoServer, but I don't know or found an example.